# Do it the "MVC" way in Ruby - or not ? (Car->Parts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, render

i`ve a theoretical question on how to implement the MVC concept the best way in Ruby (as i am more familiar with non-MVC -thx for the hint- languages like ASP, PHP).

In my example app you have to manage a *Car* and its *Parts*. Following this I would (in my opinion) implement the following two controllers:
- **CarsController**
- **PartsController**

Both have its default actions (index,show,edit,delete).

In the "index" action of the **PartsController** all linked parts for the car are displayed.

In the "index" action of the **CarsController** all car details are getting displayed and additionally I would include the content of the "index" action of the **PartsController** passing the cars id to it (or those in session).

Example layout
(CarsController/show/1)
- Car: Porsche GT
- Brand: Porsche
- Model: GT
- PS: 400
- Parts (coming from PartsController/index, parts of car were cached by CarsController before):
  *--- Doorlock

  --- Engine 400*

I tried using

```
render "cars/index"  
render :action => "cars/index"  
render :template => "cars/index"  
render :controller => "cars", :action => "index"
```

in my index.html.erb template but no one of them works (I everytime get the error message "template is missing").

Because I had a lot of trouble with this already I think my concept/implementation may be wrong.

Any suggestions on this to find a better way ?

Thank you for your help !

**UPDATE:**

Okay here is a more specific example.Lets say the user goes to localhost/cars/1. Here are the templates of my controllers for doing this:

*app/view/cars/show.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :brand %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :brand %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :model %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :model %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render "parts/index" %>
```

*app/view/parts/index.html.erb*

```
<table>
  <% @parts.each do |part| %>
  <tr id="part-<%= part.id %>">
    <td><%= part.amount %></td>
    <td><%= part.price_total %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Parts are loaded from cache therefore no car id needed for PartsController (not yet)!

*routes.rb*

```
resources :cars do
  resources :parts
end
```

Then i`ll get the following error:

> Missing partial parts/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>     * "D:/Dev/Ruby/MyCRM/app/views"
>     * "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/datagrid-0.5.3/app/views"

Comment: Neither "ASP" nor PHP are [*functional programming languages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Btw: is this for Rails? Another framework? If so, update it to reflect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're going for, here. By default, the 'index' action is about showing a list of all the things - i.e., cars/index would show all the cars. I think you're thinking of the 'show' action, which shows a single thing. i.e., cars/1 = show car 1.  ---  is it giving you a more detailed error than 'template is missing'? can you post what path it's trying to find a template at?

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. There are no non-MVC languages. Ruby was popularized because of a MVC framework for it, that doesn't make it an 'MVC' language.

Comment: Do you have a 'car' model with data for each car? Or are you trying to display a static page for just one car (no database pulling)?

Comment: There can be multiple cars and multiple parts for each car (m:n). The routes in my inital post were wrong sorry for that fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It like what you're trying to do is called 'rendering a partial' in Rails.

The basic idea is, you have a stub piece of html (in this case, a parts template to render a list of parts for a certain car), and that piece gets included in one or more full pages.

```
render "parts/index"
```

isn't working, because it's looking for a *partial* named 'index' under the parts folder, not a full page. By convention, partials in Rails are named with a leading underscore.

To get this to work, you should create a partial, i.e., app/views/parts/_list.html.erb

The second part is, that partial will need to have access to the parts list. Unless your car controller creates an @parts variable, this will need to be deduced. The way this is done in practice is by passing local variables. So, you'd rewrite _list.html.erb to use 'parts' instead of '@parts', then in your car controller, you'd render it like this:

```
render "parts/list", :locals => {:parts => @car.parts}
```

in your index for parts, if you want to list *all* the parts, you'd render the partial like this:

```
render "list", :locals => {:parts => @parts}
```

for more information, and a more detailed walkthrough, read:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: Thank you very much Yen for this detailed explanation. I will give it a try and put feedback here. Thanks !

Comment: Hey yen. Thank you i`ve got it up and running. Seems to be the right way for me...

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a number of different problems right now. The positive from your post is that you should have two Controllers as you listed. Routing (that's how rails handles web requests) is a very complicated topic when you are new, but extremely important.

I'd suggest you start with [this document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and if you are still having questions after that to ask again.

Comment: Hi, thank you I fixed the routes in my initial post (my fault).

Comment: What is the full directory that you have this in? `PartsController/index.html.erb` The way you have your routes setup, rails is looking for it in `app/views/parts/`

Comment: Hey mike, added absolute paths in my first post (project was created with RubyMine so directory structure should be ok.